# How to keybind the return to the "=" code: Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I am trying to keybind the enter key to "=".

With the code I have now, I get an error when i put in two numbers and press enter, the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 1550, in __call__
return self.func(*args)

line 68, in <lambda>
root.bind('<Return>', lambda x: Calculator.calcu('='))
TypeError: calcu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry_num'
```

The fact that the random window pops up at the start is just evidence that it's not working I guess. I believe that if the root window problem gets fixed, it could fix the key bind problem.

I get that error as I press enter, there is also a random window that opens up as I run the code as well if that helps anyone helping trying to solve the problem, please help me I'm really stuck.

**THE OVERALL PROBLEM IS:**
I don't know how to key bind the enter key on my keyboard to "=" and make the entry get entered by doing so.

[This is what I get when i run my code(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgSvz.png)

```
    from __future__ import division
from functools import partial 
from math import * 
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *  
root=Tk()
class Calculator(tk.Tk): 
def __init__(self):     
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.buttons_layout()       
    self.title("Thomas's calc") 
    textb = Entry(root)

def calcu(self,entry_num):

    if entry_num == "=":  
        try: 
            total=eval(self.textb.get()) 
            self.textb.insert(tk.END," = "+str(total)) 
        except: 
            self.textb.insert(tk.END, " - Invalid Calculation - ") 


    elif entry_num == "del":
        self.txt=self.textb.get()[:-1]
        self.textb.delete(0,tk.END)
        self.textb.insert(0,self.txt)

    elif entry_num == "C":
        self.textb.delete(0,END) 

    elif entry_num == "i":      
        infob= Toplevel(self.textb.insert(tk.END, ""))   
        infob = Label(infob, text="Thomas, Calculator").pack()  


    else: 
        if "=" in self.textb.get(): 
            self.textb.delete(tk.END)           
        self.textb.insert(tk.END, entry_num)

def buttons_layout(self): 

    self.textb = tk.Entry(root, width=66, fg="white", bg="black", state="normal") #text color = fg // background colour bg // sets the entry box specs
    self.textb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5) 

    buttona="groove"                       

    ycol = 0                         

    xrow = 1                                     

    button_list = ["1","2","3","+","C",
                   "4","5","6","-","del",       
                   "7","8","9","/","",
                   "0",".","i","*","="]

    for button in button_list:             
        calc1=partial(self.calcu, button) 
        tk.Button(root,text=button,height=4,command=calc1,bg="aquamarine", fg="red",width=10,state="normal",relief=buttona).grid(
            row=xrow, column=ycol)
        ycol= ycol + 1 
        if ycol > 4:  
            ycol=0  
            xrow= xrow + 3 

class key_binding():
    root.bind('<Return>', lambda x: Calculator.calcu('='))

end=Calculator()
end.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

THE KEYBIND IS AT THE BOTTOM OF MY CODE BY THE WAY

Comment: Post the error here directly as text. Don't post pictures of text.

Comment: then you need to explain what doesn't work. I looked at your picture, and it's barely helpful. State **exactly** what you expect to happen, and **exactly** what went wrong. If you think that picture really is the best description of your problem, you need to post it here directly. If the image is removed from the other site, your question loses meaning. Regardless, you need to explain what about the behaviour in the picture is wrong.

Comment: Okay I made it really clear this time <3

Comment: See answer below and please mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I've also got rid of the second window that wasn't needed

```
from __future__ import division
from functools import partial 
from math import * 
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *  
#root=Tk()
class Calculator(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self):     
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.buttons_layout()       
        self.title("Thomas's calc") 
        textb = Entry(self)
        self.bind('<Return>', lambda x: self.calcu('='))

    def calcu(self,entry_num):

        if entry_num == "=":  
            try: 
                total=eval(self.textb.get()) 
                self.textb.insert(tk.END," = "+str(total)) 
            except: 
                self.textb.insert(tk.END, " - Invalid Calculation - ") 


        elif entry_num == "del":
            self.txt=self.textb.get()[:-1]
            self.textb.delete(0,tk.END)
            self.textb.insert(0,self.txt)

        elif entry_num == "C":
            self.textb.delete(0,END) 

        elif entry_num == "i":      
            infob= Toplevel(self.textb.insert(tk.END, ""))   
            infob = Label(infob, text="Thomas, Calculator").pack()  


        else: 
            if "=" in self.textb.get(): 
                self.textb.delete(tk.END)           
            self.textb.insert(tk.END, entry_num)

    def buttons_layout(self): 

        self.textb = tk.Entry(self, width=66, fg="white", bg="black", state="normal") #text color = fg // background colour bg // sets the entry box specs
        self.textb.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5) 

        buttona="groove"                       

        ycol = 0                         

        xrow = 1                                     

        button_list = ["1","2","3","+","C",
                       "4","5","6","-","del",       
                       "7","8","9","/","",
                       "0",".","i","*","="]

        for button in button_list:             
            calc1=partial(self.calcu, button) 
            tk.Button(self,text=button,height=4,command=calc1,bg="aquamarine", fg="red",width=10,state="normal",relief=buttona).grid(
                row=xrow, column=ycol)
            ycol= ycol + 1 
            if ycol > 4:  
                ycol=0  
                xrow= xrow + 3 

#class key_binding():
#    root.bind('<Return>', lambda x: Calculator.calcu('='))

end=Calculator()
end.mainloop()
#root.mainloop()
```